# Selective enough to consider only few values on the file in HIVE

Tags: hadoop, hive

In HIVE can we be selective enough to consider only few values on the file ?

For Example :-

INPUT FILE :-

Tom,3654,IT,300$
Albert,3454,Manufacturing,600$
Harry,2332,SportsPerson,700$

I need to create an external table where I just need to consider only few fields . Please find the below fields which I need to consider.

3654,300$
3454,600$
2332,700$

My external table should only contain the above values and the other values should be omitted . Can it be achieved through HIVE ?

Kindly help....

Answer (score 0):

There is no OOTB feature that allows this, AFAIK. As a workaround you could create 2 tables, load the input file into first table, select the desired fields from it and insert them into the second table. Something like this :

> hive> create external table t1(c1 string, c2 string, c3 string, c4
>   string, c5 string, c6 string, c7 string, c8 string, c9 string, c10
>   string) row format delimited fields terminated by ',' location
>   '/inputs';
>
> hive> create table t2(c1 string, c2 string, c3 string, c4 string);
>
> hive> insert into table t2 select c2, concat_ws(" ", split(c4, '
>   ')[0], c5), concat_ws(" ", split(c7, ' ')[0], c8), c10 from t1;
>
> hive> select * from t2;

Comment: Can you please clarify me whats the diffrence between

Comment: Difference between what?

Comment: oops Sorry !!!! was a typo ....What is the significance of these lines "ROW FORMAT DELIMITED" "FIELDS TERMINATED BY" "LINES TERMINATED BY" ?

Comment: NP.. "FIELDS TERMINATED BY" signifies delimiter between the fields of a row, while "LINES TERMINATED BY" signifies the row delimiter. For example, comma can be used as a field delimiter and \n can be used as the row delimiter.